# NodeJS Express: different urls for different view directories?

Tags: node.js, express

From the docs I know, I can set my Express 4.12.x to use multiple views directories as follows:

```
app.set('views', [
    __dirname + '/views1',
    __dirname + '/views2'
]);
```

But I would like to have different urls get views from different views directories. So I'd like sth like:

```
app.get('/views1/:view', function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.view);  //get the views only from /views1
});
app.get('/views2/:view', function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.view);  //get the views only from /views2
});
```

What happens at the moment is that Express always checks for `:view` in `/views1` and then in `/views2`, regardless of the url. I know this is the normal behaviour of Express but I would love to know if it's possible to get my idea working.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading Express docs, I just managed to get it working by using Express subapps as middlewares:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var views1app = express();
var views2app = express();

views1app.set('views', __dirname + '/views1');
views1app.set('view engine', 'pug');
views1app.get('/views1/:view', function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.view);
});

views2app.set('views', __dirname + '/views2');
views2app.set('view engine', 'pug');
views2app.get('/views2/:view', function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params.view);
});

app.use(views1app, views2app);
```